# Bash/Shell: analyse tab-separated CSV for lines with data in n-th column

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk

I have a  tab-separated CSV, to big to download and open locally.

I want to show any lines with data in the n-th column, that is those lines with anything else than a tab right before the n-th tab of that line.

I´d post what I´ve tried so far, but my sed-knowledge is merely enough to assume that it can be done with sed.

**edit1:**

sample

```
id num name title
1  1   foo  foo
2  2        bar
3  3   baz  baz
```

If n=3 (name), then I want to output the rows 1+3.

If n=4 (title), then I want to output all the lines.

**edit 2:**

I found this possible solution:

```
awk -F '","'  'BEGIN {OFS=","} { if (toupper($5) == "STRING 1")  print }' file1.csv > file2.csv
```

source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97070/filter-a-csv-file-based-on-the-5th-column-values-of-a-file-and-print-those-reco

But trying

```
awk -F '"\t"'  'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} { if (toupper($72) != "")  print }' data.csv > data-tmp.csv
```

did not work (result file empty), so I propably got the \t wrong? (copy&paste without understanding awk)

Comment: what is difference between name and title. What I see is name can be null but title is not otherwise both are same. Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure I understand your desired behaviour. Is this it?

```
$ cat file
id      num     name    title
1       1       foo     foo
2       2               bar
3       3       baz     baz

$ awk -v n=3 -F$'\t' 'NR>1&&$n!=""' file
1       1       foo     foo
3       3       baz     baz

$ awk -v n=4 -F$'\t' 'NR>1&&$n!=""' file
1       1       foo     foo
2       2               bar
3       3       baz     baz
```

Comment: Perfect, the second one does exactly the job. (I really need to learn awk). Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I'll assume you have enough space on the remote machine:

1) use `cut` to get the desired column N (delimiter is tab by standard)

```
cut -f N > tempfile
```

2) get line numbers only of non-empty lines

```
grep -c '^$' -n tempfile | sed 's/:.*//' > linesfile
```

3) use sed to extract lines

```
while read $linenumber ; do
    sed "$linenumber p" >> newdatafile
done < linesfile
```

Unfortunately the line number cannot be extracted by piping the cut output to grep, but I am pretty sure there are more elegant solutions.